# What types of error when using the wrong format specifier in printf

Tags: c, printf, syntax-error, runtime-error

Floating-point format specifier is used in printf by the argument has a integer number. What kind of error is it? Is it a run-time error or a syntax error?

error message is shown below

```
clang-7 -pthread -lm -o main main.c
main.c:21:46: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument
      has type 'double' [-Wformat]
  ...and the processed value is %d\n", processed_value); // wron...
                                ~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                %f
```

Comment: It's not a syntax error. It is undefined behaviour and may be diagnosed at compile-time or run-time

Comment: ... or it might not be diagnosed automatically at all. Why does it matter to you what "type" of error it is?

Comment: Is will be a run-time error if code executes.

Comment: The error is not a syntax error. The error is detectable at compile time, that is, simply by examining the code without attempting to execute it. Some compilers will detect it. Some will not. The error may (likely will) also manifest when the program is executed. So it is a run-time compile-time likely-diagnosed error.

Answer (score 2):

This is describing a runtime error.

The compiler is warning you, though the print format expects an `int` (because of the `%d`), you passed it a `double`.  If you meant to pass it a double, then change the `%d` to a `%f`.

Since it's only a warning and not an error, the program still compiled.  However, as M.M mentioned in the comments, it will result in undefined behavior when you run it and, therefore, you should resolve it.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question does not ask whether the compiler will warn or what the behavior will be or will not be or whether it should be resolved or whether the program will compile. The question asks what kind of error it is.

Comment: And I explained that it’s not an error but a warning.  I also explained what kind of warning it was.

Comment: What kind of a message a particular compiler produces is not the same thing as what kind of error is in the source code. The fact that a compiler only warned and failed to diagnose an error does not mean the source code is not in fact erroneous. It is erroneous: If this program is intended to print the `double` value of `processed_value`, then it has a bug, because the `d` conversion specifier will not work for this purpose. This is an error even if the compiler does not say so, or if the compiler only warns about it.

Comment: I agree.  I also explained what the error was and how to resolve it.

Comment: Perhaps this conversation would be helped if you would be more specific. What datum do you feel is missing from my answer?  You claim that I did not explain that the source code was erroneous in its misuse of conversion specifiers.  That is manifestly false to anyone who reads my answer.

Comment: My comments do not say you did not say the source code was erroneous; no sentence says that. Although, if they did say that, they would not be false, as no sentence in the answer says the source code is erroneous. There are sentences that say, for example, that the “print format” (whatever that is” expects an `int` but was passed a `double`, but that sentence does not explicitly say that is an error. Perhaps you intended that to be conveyed implicitly, but that is not the same as saying it.

Comment: However, discussion of whether the answer says the source code is erroneous or not is irrelevant. My complaint about the answer is stated in my first comment: This answer does not state what **kind** of error it is, and that is what the question asks. An answer should state whether it is a run-time error, a semantic error, a compile-time error, a syntax error, some combination, et cetera.

Comment: That is the very definition of nitpicking.  I explained what the user had done, explained what he should have done, how not correcting his work would lead to undefined behavior, and that he should rectify his mistake.  Other than the explicit statement, “This is an error,” I don’t see how I could have been clearer.

Comment: And I did explain what type of error it was.  I said that it would lead to undefined behavior at **runtime**.

Comment: The questions **asks** “What kind of error is it?” It does not ask for a correction. The OP **knows** where the code is wrong, what is wrong with it, and how to fix it. They did not ask you for any of that. They asked for a **classification** of the error. This answer does not give that. It does not answer the question that was asked.

Comment: You and I are apparently at a standstill.  You claim my answer does not contain the relevant information and I can’t for the life of me see how you could come to that conclusion.  Let’s leave it at that.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a syntax error, because the program still follows the syntactic and semantic structure of a C program. But it is an invalid use of a standard library function,
that has been specified as having undefined behaviour. As a courtesy new C compilers diagnose format string problems wherever they can.

Answer (score 1):

This is a static semantic error which is picked up by the semantic analizer at compile time. The semantic analizer is the third stage of compilation, after the lexical analyzer and syntax analyzer.

A big clue is that C shows the warning at compile time. This doesn't mean that it won't also be a problem at run-time. But it is telling you about it during compilation.

It is not a syntax error, because it is valid syntaxically for C grammar. It is a semantic error because it is incorrect in terms of it's known meaning. Sometimes syntax and static (compile time) semantic errors can be quite difficult to distinguish and perhaps you will have to ask someone who implemented the language or studied it closely to get an accurate read.
For instance, if you had left out the format specifier altogether you could argue it is more of a syntax error as the printf() function definition requires a format specifier where a variable is given. However these are very fine distinctions.

However, even if if this code doesn't necessarily break at run-time, but if it gives you a different than expected result, then you have information from the compiler to check against.